# Symfony2 - How to get custom header while testing REST API

Tags: rest, symfony, testing, http-headers

I'm testing `REST-API`. In my `DefaultTestController`

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request(
        'GET',
        "someurl",
        [],
        [],
        [
            'HTTP_X_AUTH_TOKEN' => $clientAuthToken,
        ]
    );
```

In my `REST-controller` I'm waiting to get `x-auth-token` header

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$authToken = $request->headers->get('x-auth-token');
```

but I don't. Whats I do wrong?

Comment: I forgot to say, that I'm using FOSRestBundle. When I do the same with native application (not REST), everything is OK. But when I'm testing REST API requests through FOSRestBundle, I lost my custom headers.

Answer (score 1):

In your REST-CONTROLLER you can access to the current request passing it to the methods as follow example:

```
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
  $authToken = $request->headers->get('x-auth-token'); 
}
```

Instead of creating a new empty one.

Hope this help

Comment: Yep, you are absolutely right! I should not use CreateFromGlobal() to get a request object, but I should use from action one. It happens because of non-web call of this controller, for example testing, like in my case.